# How can i write multiple conditions in a while loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have written the following code to delete all children of theLeftSide and theRightSide. But this doesn't work. However if I write these conditions separately using one loop for each condition it works correctly.

```js
while(theLeftSide.firstChild && theRightSide.firstChild)
{
   theLeftSide.removeChild(theLeftSide.firstChild);
   theRightSide.removeChild(theRightSide.firstChild);    
}
```

Comment: Because the loop will only run as long as both `theLeftSide` and `theRightSide` have a `firstChild`. So the loop will stop as soon as one if them does not have  children anymore no matter if the other one still has.

Comment: In what sense does it not work? As written, the `while` condition will cause the loop to continue as long as both elements have children. As soon as one element is empty, the loop finishes. If that's not what you want, then what *do* you want?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, whether this is what you are trying to achieve. Probably if either one of the side has more no of child than other, your logic doesnt work. Try using `||` (OR) operator instead of `&&` (AND). And you handle the remove child function internally

```js
while(theLeftSide.firstChild || theRightSide.firstChild) {
    theLeftSide.firstChild ? theLeftSide.removeChild(theLeftSide.firstChild) : null;
    theRightSide.firstChild ? theRightSide.removeChild(theRightSide.firstChild) : null;
}
```

Comment: I tried using || and yes theLeftSide has more number of children than theRightSide

Comment: any improvement? if you have resolved it you can add your answer too

Comment: Yes. I made two functions separately and it worked! Thank you

Comment: good to know. :) you can add your answer as solution, so that it would be helpful for others who need.